# Simplifying a logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[image]

Can someone explain the logic behind the two steps? I can't figure out how to get the S in the denominator. Thanks!

Comment: (1) combine the inside expression with a common denominator. (2) the minus sign outside becomes a $(-1)$ power inside, so you can flip the fraction. Done.

Comment: Wow that should been obvious to me. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @quasi Please make this an answer. Your comment alone is complete, as evidenced by the upvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Combine the inside expression with a common denominator.

(2) The minus sign outside becomes a $\small{(−1)}$ power inside, so you can flip the fraction.

Done.